# Is it possible to redirect stdin/stdout with go:generate

Tags: go

I have a tool that acts as a pipe, it reads data from stdin and writes go source code to stdout.

Is it possible to setup input/output redirection and use such tool with go:generate? Something like:

```
//go:generate tool < file.txt > file.go
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

```
//go:generate sh -c "tool < file.txt > file.go"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not portable